# How to format Ajax 'data' string with dynamic checkbox ul list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery and more specifically ajax.

I have created a form including text fields as well as a dynamic dropdown ul list pulled from a MySQL table. I use a PHP script that checks for empty fields and at least one checkbox is checked in the form and returns `true` if these conditions are met . I have tested the `meeting_new_validation.php` and the values I want to return are working fine but my ajax is not effectively talking to it. I am almost positive the error exists at the 'data' string. I am not sure how to format the `data` string with the inclusion of the dynamic drop down ul list.  Here is what I have:

FORM

```
<form id="new_meeting_form" action="meeting_new_validation.php" method="POST">
  Meeting Name:
  <input type="text" id="meeting_topic" name="meeting_topic" placeholder="ex: ARIA Budget" class="input"/>
  <?php
  require_once('php/config.php');
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tapp_contact_list";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query error: " . mysqli_error($con));
  ?>
  <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown"><small id="counter"></small>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <?php
      $i=1;
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){     
        echo '<li><input type="checkbox" id="element-'.$i.'" name="checked[]" value='.$row['Names'].'><label for="element-'.$i.'">'.$i.'. '.$row['Names'].'</label> </li>';
        $i++;
      }?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  Meeting Location:
  <input type="text" id="meeting_location" name="meeting_location" class="input"/>
  Meeting Agenda:
 <input type="text" id="meeting_agenda" name="meeting_agenda" class="input"/>
 <input type="button" name="start" class="new_meeting_validation" onclick="new_meeting_validation()" value="START" />
 <div id="add_err"><br></div>
</form>
```

php script checking for empty fields: meeting_new_validation.php

```
<?php
$topic = $_POST['meeting_topic'];
$checked = $_POST['checked'];
$location = $_POST['meeting_location'];
$agenda = $_POST['meeting_agenda'];

if($topic == ""){
  echo '*Please enter a meeting name';
}
elseif($checked == ""){
  echo '*Please select people at the meeting';
}
elseif($location == ""){
  echo '*Please enter a meeting location';
}
elseif($agenda == ""){
  echo '*Please enter a meeting agenda';
}
else{
  echo 'true';
}
?>
```

JQUERY:

```
function new_meeting_validation(){
  var meetingTopic=$('#meeting_topic').val();
  var meetingLocation=$('#meeting_location').val();
  var checkbox=$("#checked").val();
  var meetingAgenda=$('#meeting_agenda').val();
  var dataString = 'meeting_topic='+meetingTopic+'checked='+checkbox+'meeting_location='+meetingLocation+'meeting_agenda='+meetingAgenda;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "meeting_new_validation.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
  var result=trim(result);
  if(result=='true'){
        $("#meeting_new_b").fadeOut('slow');
        window.location='meeting_page.php'; 
      }
      else{
        $("#add_err").fadeIn('normal').html(result);
      }
    }
  }); //end ajax
  return false;
} //end new_meeting_validation

function trim(str){
  var str=str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
  return str;
}
```

I believe its just a formatting error? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's built-in [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function:

```
function new_meeting_validation(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "meeting_new_validation.php",
    data: $('#new_meeting_form').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
    ...
```

That will give you the complete form, regardless of when what field was added.

On the server side you need to use `isset` to check what checkboxes were checked as unchecked checkboxes do not get sent to the server.

Comment: Works great thanks for the tip @jeroen.  I am trying to add a variable defined above `$.ajax({` called `var loadTimeout = setTimeout(tick, 15100);` for a time out function.  However, when I put a the variable there the ajax no longer works. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: @Rob Where is the `tick()` function?

Comment: Oh sorry I made a dump error. In efforts to simplify my code for this post I accidentally deleted it. everything works fine. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

im not sure how jquery converts things but as your data string looks now it would be this:

"meeting_topic=meetingTopicValuechecked=checkboxValuemeeting_location=meetingLocationValuemeeting_agenda=meetingAgendaValue"

from what i can see there are no separators between the values and the next name? Is this correct formatting for jquery?